# "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" with a custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository, custom-model-binder

I've been following Darin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964723/729541) to a question I had on slimming down my controllers and I'm running into problems with this `IEntityChangeTracker` exception:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Here's my model binder:

```
public class PostModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IPostRepository _repository;

    public PostModelBinder(IPostRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var postIDValue = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("postID");
        int postID;

        if (postIDValue == null || !int.TryParse(postIDValue.AttemptedValue, out postID))
            return null;

        return _repository.FindPost(postID, filterByPublished: true);
    }
}
```

After this, my custom action filter simply carries out a bit of validation on the post and redirects if the post isn't valid.  Up until this point, everything is fine.  The error happens in my controller when I try to update the post read count:

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    private IPostRepository postRepository;

    // snip...

    [AutoMap(typeof(Post), typeof(PostViewModel)), HttpGet]
    [PostActionFilter]
    public ActionResult ShowPost(Post model)
    {
        postRepository.PostVisited(model);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I understand `IEntityChangeTracker`'s complaining  because I effectively end up with 2 repositories referencing the same object and that just seems like bad mojo waiting to happen.  I know I could push the `PostVisited()` call into `PostModelBinder` but updating a model doesn't seem like behaviour that belongs there.

Is there another way around this?

Thank you.

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you posting to ShowPost but specifying HttpGet, and then in turn showing a View, rather than redirecting to a HttpGet action (Post/Redirect/Get pattern?) am I reading this properly?

Comment: @AdamTuliper ShowPost is displaying a blog post within my PostsController.  It's not handling HttpPost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, I assume your two `IPostRepository` implementation objects use different Entity Framework object contexts; you can fix this by using the same object context throughout a request.

Some DI containers support per-request object lifetimes, otherwise you can lazy-load and store your object context in `HttpContext.Items` and dispose of it at the end of the request, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688772/c-sharp-entity-framework-using-only-one-objectcontext-per-httpcontext).

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer and the question link.  Does this mean I'd create an object manager for the context, create a new context on each request, give that to the repositories in their constructors and then dispose of the context at the end of the request?

Comment: Sorry it's taken me such a long time to accept your answer.  I was sick for a few weeks and after that I decided this was a good excuse to learn to use dependency injection.  I ended up having to ask a related question for Ninject and I've [self-answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9231697/729541) that question with a test implementation, for anyone interested.

Comment: Hey John, no problem, glad you're feeling better. Good for you for going the more 'proper' route and using DI :)

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the help and the words of encouragement.  Have a good weekend! :)