# Issue with resolving dependencies in model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I'm working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4 application + NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate + Ninject` application.

I've created a separate module to resolve the dependencies of `ISession` and `ISessionFactory` s below,

```
  public class RepositoryModule: NinjectModule
  {
    public override void Load()
    {
      Bind<ISessionFactory>()
        .ToMethod(e => Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DbConnString")))
        .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Post>())            
        .BuildConfiguration()
        .BuildSessionFactory())
        .InSingletonScope();

      Bind<ISession>()
        .ToMethod((ctx) => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
        .InRequestScope();
    }
  }
```

I've a repository class `BlogRepository` that implements `IBlogRepository`.

```
  public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
  {
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public BlogRepository(ISession session)
    {
      _session = session;
    }

    public IList<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
    {
      var query = _session.Query<Post>()
                          .Where(p => p.Published)
                          .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
                          .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                          .Take(pageSize)
                          .Fetch(p => p.Category);

      query.FetchMany(p => p.Tags).ToFuture();

      return query.ToFuture().ToList();
    }

    // others
  }
```

I need an instance of `BlogRepository` in a custom model binder.

I've tried something like this in the Global.asax.cs.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Post), new PostModelBinder(Kernel.Get<IBlogRepository>()));
```

At the first request everything works fine but from the second request I'm getting

> session is closed error

. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ModelBinder` has longer lifecycle than one request. As you can see you are registering `PostModelBinder` using the `new` operator. MVC application keeps reference to this binder and the binder has reference to `IBlogRepository`, whose `ISession` will be disposed at the end of the first request.

You can solve this by using **factory**:

Instead of `IBlogRepository` you will inject factory `IBlogRepositoryFactory` object, and then create new `IBlogRepository` on each `BindModel` call.

To accomplish this, you can use [Ninject factory extension](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/).

Or by create own factory as described here in accepted answer: [Inject a dependency into a custom model binder and using InRequestScope using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186560/inject-a-dependency-into-a-custom-model-binder-and-using-inrequestscope-using-ni)